# Vbscript how to name a txt file with the next notation: "test_date_time.log"

Tags: vbscript, basic

I tried to make a script to generate log files with the characteristics as follow:
 "test_date_time.log"
my script is like this:

Set objfso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

informacion = " " & DATE & " " & TIME & " "

Set archivoog = objfso.createtextfile("C:\Users\gdlabrui\Desktop\Pick_folder\programs\vbs\ex1 searchAstringAndCopyingOnTxt\" & informacion & ".log",true)

but it appears an error but i dont know how to follow.

Update: Error: Bad file name or number

Code: 800A0034

Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error.

Comment: What error are you getting? please update your question with the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the automatic conversion of **DATE** and **TIME** to string is not recommended because the format is only defined by your current regional settings. The format of DATE and TIME will change if the script is run on a different computer with different regional settings. This format could have forward slashes (/) in it that could make your file creation impossible in a single command because those would represents subfolders that do not yet exists.

What I recommend you is to make yourself a function that will generate a string that represents date and time in a format that you have 100% control over. You can take this one below if you want. It will generate date and time in the YYYYMMDD_HHMM format.

```
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set LogFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\gdlabrui\Desktop\Pick_folder\programs\vbs\ex1 searchAstringAndCopyingOnTxt\" + CurrentDateTimeText() + ".log",true)

Function CurrentDateTimeText()

    CurrentDateTimeText = CStr(Year(Now))+ _
                          Right("0"+CStr(Month(Now)),2)+ _
                          Right("0"+CStr(Day(Now)),2) + "_" + _
                          Right("0"+CStr(Hour(Now)),2) + _
                          Right("0"+CStr(Minute(Now)),2)

End Function
```